# Display warnings in sbt continuous compilation mode

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am running "activator ~run" on my scala project to have it update immediately after I make a change to the code.

This works nicely, but I dont see any warnings any more on subsequent compiles. The only thing I see is "[success] Compiled in xs".

Now i do see the warnings immediately after running "activator ~run" for the first time. I do not see it after I make code changes and save them.

How can I get sbt to display the warnings on each refresh, so that I can work on them?

I'm using sbt 013.5, scala 2.11.2, activator 1.2.7

Comment: sbt will only recompile changed files. So, if you didn't change a file it also won't show the warnings. One way to "solve" this is to promote warnings to errors by adding the scala compiler option `-Xfatal-warnings`.

Comment: ok, that makes sense, you can't have your cake and eat it